# Doesnt kernel garantee backward compatibility on compiled files?

Tags: linux, gcc

Briefly: Is Linux kernel 2.6.32 compiled executable incompatible with a Linux Kernel 2.6.24 kernel?

I have a executable that I compiled in a system with linux 2.6.32 kernel. When I transfer the compiled file to a linux 2.6.24 system, I get the following error when executing:

```
bremm@bezier:/tmp/deployed$ ./qt-workstation
bash: ./qt-workstation: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

The text means "file or directory not found", but the file exists. The output of strace:

```
execve("./qt-workstation", ["./qt-workstation"], [/* 46 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78e84f5000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f78e84f5000, 4096)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: I am not even sure if the kernel version is the problem, I am looking for some light in my problem. Unfortunately I couldnt reproduce the problem in a smaller code yet. Any suggestion may help me.

Comment: I think that text means 'file or directory not found', so use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find which file it's missing.

Comment: Uh, no. "The kernel" might guarantee backward compatibility of *binary formats*, but this is not "compiled files" or "linked libraries". Generally, however, breaking changes are frowned upon and very rare in the kernel API and established libraries; it could be the case that a required library is simply absent. In any case, there is no guarantee by "the kernel".

Comment: Sorry, forgot to translate the output. It meant file not found, but the file exists. With strace I notice that the sycall is saying that the file was not found...

Comment: Aha. What does `file qt-workstation` tell you?

Comment: `qt-workstation: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0xd0bfe8206a1f25c0c455d202403aaf82a639a268, not stripped`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is related to dynamic linking.  I believe I've seen errors like this from compiled executables that couldn't find ld.so or ld-linux.so or similar.

For #!'d scripts, this can happen when the #!'d interpreter isn't found - including when the script was transferred from windows and has a control-M at the end of the pathname.

## Update

Running `strings ./qt-workstation | head` I found out that my ld-linux.so was hardcoded to `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (the first output of the command), on the Ubuntu this file is located elsewhere.

Creating a symbolic to `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` solves the problem.

Comment: Your suggestion is very promising, I will check it and will give a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message there is complaining about a missing file, so you need to find what that file is. Use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) thus:

```
strace -o trace -f ./qt-workstation 
grep ENOENT trace
```

and start looking backwards from the last result. One of the results should be your missing file.

Comment: I've added strace output to my question. As you can see, it complains the executable itself wasnt found...

Answer (score 0):

`Bash` is the one saying `/tmp/deployed/qt-workstation` is not found, are you sure file is there?

Comment: I guarantee for you that the file exists. Also, when the file doesnt exist, strace doesnt even start...